# Custom Facebook Share using Sharer.php

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question and answer section on my website and I am trying to integrate social media sharing into each question on the forum. I basically just want the user to be able to share the individual question on their timeline. I am currently using the sharer.php method, which I believe is no longer deprecated. See below:

```
 window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + "" + fullHREF,"","height=550,width=525,left=100,top=100,menubar=0");
```

At this point, the facebook post content is my site title, and my site's home url...but the link DOES direct you to the individual question. In the facebook post I want: my company logo, the question title, and a link to my site. What is the best way to accomplish this? Sorry for the vague nature of the question, I am new to the  relatively new to Facebook's API. I have been looking into Facebook's OpenGraph Stories, but I think that would be more appropriate for when a user answers a question on my site, and the story would read..Joe Blow ANSWERED a QUESTION on example.com.
In this part of the site, I just want users to be able to share the question title. I would also like to have my company logo as the image in the facebook post content...but no image is showing up right now, although I have an image defined in the og:image tag. Thanks in advance.

Comment: fullHREF is dynamically created and is the url of the individual question to be shared.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are looking for:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Make sure the parameters are correct.

For link problem, ensure the "fullHREF" is cleaned by urlencode(). Cos a "hash" would break the sharer function in my experience.

For the company logo, use the debug tool:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing

You can scrape again to get the latest image you set in the meta tag. If it is still not showing the correct one, you might have the tag wrongly configured.

If you want to have dynamic image on the post, you should consider to use feed dialog:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: FYI for anyone reading this as of 05/2017 - Facebook has removed fields for custom text/image/etc from the Share Dialog as well as the Feed Dialog.